# Select table row by id begins with and name

Tags: jquery, each

Seems like something this simple should be straightforward but apparently I'm not getting it...

I need to iterate over every table row (`.each`) with an id beginning with "pc-" (`"tr[id^='pc-']`) and has a specific name (`[name='someValue']`). What I have so far:

```
$("tr[id^='pc-'] name=" + $(this).attr("appliesto") + " ").each(function ()...
```

The examples I've seen so far would say something like:

```
$("#someID[name='somevalue']".somethingsomethingsomething...
```

but obviously it's not working.... I know the problem would be the space between the selectors but how would you chain selectors in this instance?

What do I need to have instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close:

```
$("tr[id^='pc-'][name=" + $(this).attr("appliesto") + "]").each(function ()...
```

Or to make it a little more clear:

```
var name = $(this).attr("appliesto");

$("tr[id^='pc-'][name=" + name + "]").each(function ()...
```

Really if all you want is the `appliesto` attribute value, you can omit jQuery:

```
var name = this.getAttribute("appliesto");

$("tr[id^='pc-'][name=" + name + "]").each(function ()...
```

No need to create a new jQuery object when a simple call to `this.getAttribute(...)` will suffice.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I take it that selectors can chain but you enclose each in brackets?

Comment: Correct. The attribute selectors should not be separated by any characters. The space character is the descendent selector, so you want `[attr1=value1][attr2=value2]`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :)